# Convert .m file into .mlx file from command window

Tags: matlab, command-line-interface

I know that `.m` files (in particular, function files) can be converted to `.mlx` files (preserving code comments and formatting) by right clicking the file and selecting 'Open as Live Script'.

Is it possible to also generate (and save) the same data as a Live Script/Live Function using the command line?

Comment: `doc matlab.internal.richeditor.openAndSave` does not seem to work in R2023b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open a string of code as a live script using the `matlab.internal.liveeditor.openAsLiveCode`. To convert from a .m file you can use `fileread` first to create that string from the .m file.

The below was tested in R2022b.

```
filepath = 'C:\foo\untitled.m'; % some .m file we want to convert
matlab.internal.liveeditor.openAsLiveCode(fileread(filepath)); % open as live script
```

It's slightly painful to save the file because the opening function above doesn't return a handle to the newly opened document. We can get the active document from the `matlab.desktop` class and then save it:

```
activeDoc = matlab.desktop.editor.getActive(); % get the active editor (the new file)
activeDoc.saveAs( strrep(filepath,'.m','.mlx') ); % Save with same file name but .mlx
```

If you want to close the new editor window you can do `activeDoc.close()`

Result:

[image: conversion output]

Comment: This works well. As a side note - the filename used in `saveAs` has to be an absolute path.